# How to have a bidirectional fixture view like this in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a bidirectional fixture in my app. But how can i achieve a view like this in a dynamic way in flutter? Because, the team number might be different.

[image]

Comment: use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the plugin- https://pub.dev/packages/bidirectional_scroll_view though at the moment it doesn't provide smooth transitions.
You could also try using PageView with pageSnapping set to false, gives a relatively similar bi-directional scrolling experience.